# Is there any way of setting audio and video codec type in webrtc android application? I want to use aac and h264. Below is my code

Tags: android, webrtc, h.264, codec, sdp

```
    PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions initializationOptions =
            PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(context)
                    .createInitializationOptions();
    PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(initializationOptions);
    PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = new PeerConnectionFactory.Options();
    VideoEncoderFactory encoderFactory = new DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(), true, true);
    VideoDecoderFactory decoderFactory = new DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());
    for (VideoCodecInfo supportedCodec : encoderFactory.getSupportedCodecs()) {
        System.out.println("%%%%% nest supported codec"+supportedCodec.name);
    }

    peerConnectionFactory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder()
            .setOptions(options)
            .setVideoDecoderFactory(decoderFactory)
            .setVideoEncoderFactory(encoderFactory)
            .createPeerConnectionFactory();
```

the above code does not works. I tried rtpParameters but that is a private class. Other classes have no setcodec() function.